# SQL (MySQL) vs NoSQL (MongoDB) vs Other (?) for Massive Quantity of Tables

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

I'm planning a new side-project that will ultimately involve analyzing data I collect. It's mostly time series data with varying numbers of components (think relational database columns). The time series data will vary in the time periods covered and frequencies measured (so there isn't too much standardized info to combine into fewer tables). None of the time series sets will have too much data, maybe a maximum of around 100,000 measurements per series with an average of around 5000 measurements (think rows). I expect there to be at least 10,000 different sets of time series data (think tables).

I don't anticipate having to do many complex queries (and even if I did, there is nothing time-sensitive about this project as it's really just batch-style analysis so I could do complex things with software after selecting data from a DB) so I am also considering a NoSQL database like MongoDB.

Can anyone advise me on whether MySQL or MongoDB would be a better choice? If MySQL, which storage engine? If neither, do you have a better suggestion? Also, if the number of tables jumps from 10,000 to 500,000 or more, does that change your answer?

Comment: May be interesting: http://www.askbjoernhansen.com/2008/02/14/10000_tables_in_one_mysql_database.html

Comment: Can you provide an example of what your data tables may look like? From what you describe, it sounds like a simple "id, timestamp, frequency" but I may be misunderstanding.

Comment: @Justinᚅᚔᚈᚄᚒᚔ Some of it might be but not necessarily. It will range from financial data to economic data to geographic data to biological data. It's fairly open ended statistical analysis based on some ideas I'm developing. I can tell you that the columns will most likely be either ints or floats and there will be anywhere from one to ten in each table. I am certain that it won't be as basic as a key-value situation. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: This sounds less like a database and more like "big data" processing to me. You might consider storing the data in flat files and writing map/reduce jobs running on hadoop for your analysis.

Comment: @GuillaumePoussel Good stuff to know if I use MySQL. Thanks.

Comment: @TimGautier Thanks for the comment. I see how it sounds like a map/reduce job but it's not. I need the database to do 3 things: store the data, select a range between two dates, and give me the data so I can work with it in my program. I don't need it to do anything else. If not for the ability to quickly get a range of data I would just store files in directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to suggest a new DBMS called [SciDB.org](http://scidb.org).  They claim it isn't a typical DBMS because it focuses more on scientific analytical processing.  It is optimized specifically for time series data and can further be optimized to run on the cloud.

It is optimized for time series data because it stores the data in columns as opposed to rows allowing for fast access in the time dimension.

You should check it out.

I used it to analyze data that was sampling at 2000 samples per second over months of time.